# How to configure DS Replicas links in Spring Cloud Eureka Server Dashboard

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I setup an Eureka cluster composed of 3 replicas.

I got the nice dashboard which is automatically populated with the instances currently registered with Eureka and the DS Replicas.

However the DS Replicas links seems to point to the value I set as `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone`. In my case this value is something similar to `http://node-01:8761/eureka/`  which in reality returns a 404. Is there a way I could configure the dashboard to strip out the /eureka/ part so when I follow the links I end up in the other dashboards or am I misunderstanding the use of those links?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to alter the link as you ask.

However, the UI part of the Eureka server is a standard Spring MVC @Controller. An instance of it is created by `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration`. Have a look at the current implementation... it shouldn't be too hard to provide your own customized version instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. If anyone wants to know exactly how the replicas are rendered just have a look at `navbar.ftl` in the spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server JAR.